# Convert string with sed

Tags: shell, unix

I have a couple lines in my input where I am initializing structs. For example:

```
head = (struct node) {5, NULL};
```

I need to convert these lines into the following:

```
init_node( &head, 5, NULL);
```

That is...Anytime I see the following line in the input file:

```
something = (struct something2){ something3, something4};
```

I need to convert it to:

```
init_something2( &something1, something3, something4);
```

I think I need to use sed function here.
Can someone help??
Thanks

Comment: Yes, sed should work for this.  What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Sed would probably work too, but here's something that works with perl:

`perl -pe 's|(.*) = \(struct node\) {(.*), (.*)};|init_node( &\1, \2, \3);|'`

Notice that I'm capturing each "something" with a parenthetical expression in the match, and then retrieving them with \1, \2, etc. in the substitute. That's the only part you really need to know. Hopefully you can figure out how to make either expression flexible enough to fit your actual data (Unless you miraculously have a consistent style for every single line).

Comment: I forgot the second part of the question, but to cover that just replace 'node' with (.*) in the match and \2 in the substitute, then move \2 and \3 to \3 and \4.

Comment: That works nicely if there are exactly two initializers, but a trivial variation would work with an arbitrary number of initializers: `{(.*}}` to capture, though you might be safer with `{([^{}]*)}` which doesn't match `{` or `}` inside the initializer list.

Answer (score 1):

I would do:

```
sed -e 's/\s*\([_a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z_]*\)\s*=\s*(\s*struct\s*\([_a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z_]*\)\s*)\s*{\s*\([^}]*\)}\s*;/init_\2( \&\1, \3);/' -i you_file.c
```

Explaining the Crazy RegExp:

1) \s* skips zero or more whitespace (so it becomes more flexible).

Second we grab by using ( ) a C identifier which (please someone correct me if I'm wrong) can start with a character from the alphabet or an underscore, and can contain alpha-numeric characters and underscores ([*a-zA-Z][0-9a-zA-Z*]*).

Third skip an equals sign followed by zero-or-more spaces, then skip an open parenthesis followed by spaces, then a struct followed by spaces

Fourth: grab another identifier

Fifth: skip a close parenthesis surrounded by zero or more spaces, then an open bracket followed by whitespaces

Sixth: grab anything before a close bracket (beware of this! you can't have in the code an expression that contains brackets)

Seventh: Skip the close bracket then whitespaces then a semicolon

Finally: rearrange what was grabbed =)

EDIT: Notice that the "&" must be escaped: "\&". If it isn't, sed will substitute it with the whole match

EDIT2: Thanks to Jonathan for the observation related to how to include an arbitrary number of initializers (with commas)

Hope this helps,

Janito

Comment: Hello Janito...when I ran the function, I got an error that said: sed: -e expression #1, char 138: unterminated `s' command

Comment: Hello =). Sorry for the silly mistake, the final "/" was missing. I also fixed a missing "\" before the "&". Hope this fixes everything =)

Comment: You can use a slightly simpler regex and be rather more general in what you handle.  You're tied to handling two-element structures.  If you changed the value-list handling part of the regex from `{\s*\([^,]*\),\s*\([^}]*\)}` to `{\s*\([^{}]*\)}`, you could handle 1 or 3 or N initializers; the replacement string would change to: `init_\2( \&\1, \3);`.

Comment: Hello Jonathan. Excellent observation! Thank you very much for the feedback! I'll update the answer =)

Comment: Hello Janito, Do you think you can help me out with one last problem. Sed is a little confusing for me. Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12549152/using-sed-to-transform

Answer (score 0):

Regular expressions will be your friend here (assuming your input is a consistent format).

The expression `\([a-zA-Z]*\) = (struct \([a-zA-Z]*\)) {\([a-zA-Z0-9, ]*\)};` should model your input string.  Using these capture groups, the expression `init_\2( \&\1, \3);` should generate your desired output string.  Putting these together, the following `sed` command should do what you need:

```
sed -e 's/\([a-zA-Z]*\) = (struct \([a-zA-Z]*\)) {\([a-zA-Z0-9, ]*\)};/init_\2( \&\1, \3);/g'
```

This assumes that your `struct` and variable names only consist of upper- and lower-case letters (I kept it simple to try to prevent the example from becoming too wide for the page).  If they contain other characters, you'll need to adjust the expressions accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

A more general sed match:

```
sed -e 's/\([a-zA-Z0-9]*\)\s*=\s*(\s*struct\s\([a-zA-Z0-9]*\)\s*)\s*{\s*\([a-zA-Z0-9]*\)\s*,\s*\([a-zA-Z0-9]*\)\s*}\s*;/init_\2( \&\1, \3, \4);/g'
```

This would match expressions like:

- `something=( struct something2)  {something3,something4};`
- `something    =   (struct something2)  {  something3  ,   something4  };`

etc.

Comment: This still won't match valid variable symbols in most languages. I think a non-greedy .-match would be better in this case. Edit: Actually, Janito's solution is probably best because it actually *does* match valid variable symbols (in C at least, which is most likely what this is).

Comment: Hello Jon Lin...your code works well. However it only works when I have 2 inputs parameters. Can you modify it to do any number of inputs. Like for example: something=( struct something2) {something3,something4,something5,something6};